# C# Add FIELDS ( column values ) to uploaded File ( Document ) not working

Tags: c#, sharepoint

please help,

I'm trying to add FIELDS to an "just uploaded" File.
The File is uploaded to an SPFolder Object.
I want to automatically add all Fields from the Library or Folder where the
File is uploaded to the File.

1st : I get all Fields from the Library (SPList)
from the Event "ItemAdded" properties:

```
SPList currentList = properties.List;
```

2nd: I get a FIELD COLLECTION of all fields from the currentList:

```
SPFieldCollection currentListFieldItems = currentList.Fields;
```

3rd: Now I want to ADD every FIELD to the currentItem (which is the just
uploaded File):

```
for (int i = 0; i < AnzahlFields; i++)
{

                   SPField NeuesFeld = currentListFieldItems[i];
                   String FeldInternalName = currentListFieldItems[i].InternalName;
                   String FeldName = currentListFieldItems[i].Title;
                   NeuesFeld.Type = currentListFieldItems[i].Type;
                   NeuesFeld.Required = currentListFieldItems[i].Required;
                   NeuesFeld.ShowInEditForm = true;
                   NeuesFeld.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                   NeuesFeld.ShowInListSettings = true;
                   NeuesFeld.ShowInNewForm = true;
                   NeuesFeld.ShowInViewForms = true;


                   if (currentItem.Fields.ContainsField(FeldInternalName))
                   {
                   // The Field already exists
                   }
                   else
                   {
                   // The Field is not existing, will be added
                      currentItem.Fields.Add(NeuesFeld);
                   }

                   } 

currentitem.update();
```

Its not working because it always says, that all Fields already existing !
Can you help me, what do I wrong ?

Steffen

Answer (score 1):

You can not add fields to a SPListItem. The ListItem already has all fields that exist in the list you uploaded the file to.
Instead if you want to set the value of an field you can do this by using the internal name of the field:

```
currentItem["InternalNameOfField"] = "I am the new value";
```

More information and examples can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx)

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response, but when I try this , I get an error: 

Property or indexer 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.this[string]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: my fault, you have to use the indexer of the listitem, not the fields collection. Updated my answer and added a link to MSDN where you can find more information and examples

Comment: Thank you, I tried:

currentItem["InternalNameofField"] = "New Value" ;

Comment: I got an Exception Error:

'currentItem[FieldInternalName] = NeuesFeld.GetFieldValue(FieldInternalName);'

SPFieldValidationException was unhandled by user code
invalid URL: _dlc_DocIdUrl

Comment: OK, now setting the value should work, you can try this by setting a simple text field value, your current error message is a new problem I think

Comment: were you able to set the value? if so please accept the answer